# Environment variable which contains spaces can not be used in command

Tags: bash, path, environment-variables

I set an env var which contains spaces. I can output it correctly.

```
export dpath="/path/with/spaces/is here/clear"
echo $dpath
/path/with/spaces/is here/clear
```

Now use the env var here:

```
sshpass -p 'xxxx' sftp -q -a -P22 -r "account@12.34.56.78:${dpath}" .
File "/path/with/spaces/is" not found.
```

Now the space is ignored (and split). How can I fix this?

Comment: try to define it as `dpath="/path/with/spaces/is\ here/clear"`

Comment: is there another solution? I can't set the env var in another way

Comment: Does `sshpass -p 'xxxx' sftp -q -a -P22 -r account@12.34.56.78:\"${dpath}\" ` work?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to make it not split we need quotes.
Try to store env var as:
`export dpath='"/path/with/spaces/is here/clear"'`

Use " inside '.

OR if you can't store export var in this way then try to use the double quotes around the variable in the scp command:
`sshpass -p 'xxxx' sftp -q -a -P22 -r account@12.34.56.78:"${dpath}" .`

Hope this helps